# Finding the screen id of a page generated with add_menu_page

Tags: plugins, php, metabox, add-menu-page

I'm at a basic level of WordPress + PHP and I'm trying to build a pretty simple plugin.

I've set up the plugin correctly, and the plugin page is generated with

```
function wpplugin_settings_page() {
    add_menu_page(
        'Modal Generator',
        'Modal Generator',
        'manage_options',
        'modal-slug',
        'wpplugin_settings_page_markup',
        'dashicons-format-gallery',
        100
    );
}
```

Whereas `wpplugin_settings_page_markup` is a function that generates my HTML on the plugin page.

I copy-pasted a code to create/generate metaboxes and they work great. I can get them to show on posts & pages with this code:

```
function single_repeater_meta_boxes() {
    add_meta_box( 'single-repeater-data', 'Single Repeater', 'single_repeatable_meta_box_callback', 'page', 'normal', 'default');
}
```

I achieved this by changing the `$screen`-parameter, [as WordPress' official documentation states](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_meta_box/):

> **$screen**
>
> *(string|array|WP_Screen) (Optional)* The screen or screens on which to show the box (such as a post type, 'link', or 'comment'). Accepts a single screen ID, `WP_Screen` object, or array of screen IDs. Default is the current screen. If you have used `add_menu_page()` or `add_submenu_page()` to create a new screen (and hence screen_id), make sure your menu slug conforms to the limits of `sanitize_key()` otherwise the 'screen' menu may not correctly render on your page.

However, I can't get them to show on my dynamically generated plugin page. I somehow need to find the screen ID and use that as the parameter value for `$screen`. The slug `modal-generator` shouldn't be an issue. I hope my question makes sense and if not, feel free to ask.

```php
add_action('admin_init', 'single_repeater_meta_boxes', 2);

function single_repeater_meta_boxes() {
    add_meta_box( 'single-repeater-data', 'Single Repeater', 'single_repeatable_meta_box_callback', 'toplevel_page_wp-nordic-modal', 'normal', 'default');
}

/* =========== GENERATING METABOXES =========== */
function single_repeatable_meta_box_callback($post) {

    $single_repeater_group = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'single_repeater_group', true);
    $banner_img = get_post_meta($post->ID,'post_banner_img',true);
    wp_nonce_field( 'repeaterBox', 'formType' );
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
            $( '#add-row' ).on('click', function() {
                var row = $( '.empty-row.custom-repeater-text' ).clone(true);
                row.removeClass( 'empty-row custom-repeater-text' ).css('display','table-row');
                row.insertBefore( '#repeatable-fieldset-one tbody>tr:last' );
                return false;
            });

            $( '.remove-row' ).on('click', function() {
                $(this).parents('tr').remove();
                return false;
            });
        });

    </script>

    <table id="repeatable-fieldset-one" width="100%">
        <tbody>
            <?php
            if ( $single_repeater_group ) :
                foreach ( $single_repeater_group as $field ) {
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="text"  style="width:98%;" name="title[]" value="<?php if($field['title'] != '') echo esc_attr( $field['title'] ); ?>" placeholder="Heading" /></td>
                        <td><input type="text"  style="width:98%;" name="tdesc[]" value="<?php if ($field['tdesc'] != '') echo esc_attr( $field['tdesc'] ); ?>" placeholder="Description" /></td>
                        <td><a class="button remove-row" href="#1">Remove</a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                }
            else :
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text"   style="width:98%;" name="title[]" placeholder="Heading"/></td>
                    <td><input type="text"  style="width:98%;" name="tdesc[]" value="" placeholder="Description" /></td>
                    <td><a class="button  cmb-remove-row-button button-disabled" href="#">Remove</a></td>
                </tr>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <tr class="empty-row custom-repeater-text" style="display: none">
                <td><input type="text" style="width:98%;" name="title[]" placeholder="Heading"/></td>
                <td><input type="text" style="width:98%;" name="tdesc[]" value="" placeholder="Description"/></td>
                <td><a class="button remove-row" href="#">Remove</a></td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
    <p><a id="add-row" class="button" href="#">Add another</a></p>
    <?php
}

/* =========== SAVING METABOXES ===========*/
add_action('save_post', 'single_repeatable_meta_box_save');

function single_repeatable_meta_box_save($post_id) {

    if (!isset($_POST['formType']) && !wp_verify_nonce($_POST['formType'], 'repeaterBox'))
        return;

    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE)
        return;

    if (!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id))
        return;

    $old = get_post_meta($post_id, 'single_repeater_group', true);

    $new = array();
    $titles = $_POST['title'];
    $tdescs = $_POST['tdesc'];
    $count = count( $titles );
    for ( $i = 0; $i < $count; $i++ ) {
        if ( $titles[$i] != '' ) {
            $new[$i]['title'] = stripslashes( strip_tags( $titles[$i] ) );
            $new[$i]['tdesc'] = stripslashes( $tdescs[$i] );
        }
    }

    if ( !empty( $new ) && $new != $old ){
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'single_repeater_group', $new );
    } elseif ( empty($new) && $old ) {
        delete_post_meta( $post_id, 'single_repeater_group', $old );
    }
    $repeater_status= $_REQUEST['repeater_status'];
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'repeater_status', $repeater_status );
}

/* =========== PLUGIN PAGE ===========*/
function wpplugin_settings_page()
{
    add_menu_page(
        'Modal Generator',                  // page title
        'Modal Generator',                  // menu title
        'manage_options',                   // capability
        'wp-nordic-modal',                  // menu_slug
        'wpplugin_settings_page_markup',    // callable function
        'dashicons-format-gallery',         // icon
        100
    );
    add_submenu_page(
      'wp-nordic-modal',
      __( 'Popup Generator', 'wp-nordic-modal' ),
      __( 'Popup', 'wp-nordic-modal' ),
      'manage_options',
      'wpplugin-feature-1',
      'wpplugin_settings_subpage_markup'
    );

}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'wpplugin_settings_page' );


function wpplugin_settings_page_markup()
{
    // Double check user capabilities
    if ( !current_user_can('manage_options') ) {
      return;
    }?>
    <div class="wrap">
      <h1><?php esc_html_e( get_admin_page_title() ); ?></h1>
      <p><?php esc_html_e( 'Some content.', 'wpplugin' ); ?></p>
    </div>
    <div>save</div>
    <?php
}

function wpplugin_settings_subpage_markup()
{
  // Double check user capabilities
  if ( !current_user_can('manage_options') ) {
      return;
  }
  ?>
  <div class="wrap">
    <h1><?php esc_html_e( get_admin_page_title() ); ?></h1>
    <p><?php esc_html_e( 'Some content.', 'wpplugin' ); ?></p>
  </div>
  <?php
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function [`add_menu_page`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_menu_page/) return the hook suffix that inform you about the current page.

A simple example to get the hook suffix.

```
public function add_menu_page() {
    $page_hook_suffix = add_menu_page(
        esc_html__( 'Admin Page', 'translation-slug' ),
        esc_html__( 'Admin Page', 'translation-slug' ),
        'read',
        'My Name',
        array( $this, 'get_styles' )
    );
    add_action( 'admin_print_scripts-' . $page_hook_suffix, array( $this, 'enqueue_assets' ) );
}
```

The example above add the scripts only on the custom admin page, because the hook `admin_print_scripts-*` is fired only on the hook suffix from the return value of `add_menu_page`.

### `WP_Screen`

Also, you can use the function [`get_current_screen`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_current_screen/) to identify the page and use the value after identification.

### Helpers

There are also helper plugins to find this value, if is not dynamically, like [Query Monitor](https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/) and [Debug Objects](https://github.com/bueltge/debug-objects).

### Screenshot

[image: Query Monitor Current Screen]

Comment: Hi Bueltge, the Query Monitor plugin is great, thanks! However even after using the screen id as a parameter in `add_meta_box`, the metaboxes are still not generated on my plugin page. I've read answers on SO/SE WP that state it's not possible to use metaboxes on plugin pages, but I've seen a [custom plugin of yours](https://gist.github.com/bueltge/757903) that seems to generate metaboxes (can't get it to work though - outdated?) Is using screen_id not an available parameter in `add_meta_box`? I updated my Q with my full code, if that helps.